# Svelte page.js routing - Can't get passed-in props for dynamic component

Tags: routes, svelte, svelte-3, page.js

I have a problem with `page.js` routing. If I go from `settings` to a `dashboard`, i get the passed in props. If I go from `dashboard` to `dashboard` nothing is logged out... Can anyone help?

**App.svelte**

```js
let page, props;

router("/settings", () => (page = Settings));

router("/dashboards/:dashboardId", (ctx) => {
    props = ctx.params;
    console.log("App", props);
    page = Dashboard;
});

<svelte:component this={page} {...props} />
```

**Navigation.svelte**

```html
{#each $dashboards as dashboard}
    <div class="dashboard-link">
        <a href="/dashboards/{dashboard.id}">{dashboard.name}</a>
    </div>
{/each}
```

**Dashboard.svelte**

```js
<script>
    export let dashboardId;
    console.log("dashboardId", dashboardId);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code actually works. The problem was that the `console.log` works only during initialization i.e. from settings to dashboard, dashboard loads. From dashboard to dashboard, only the variables change i.e. component is already loaded.